# VB 2008 isn't debugging without internet connection

Tags: vb.net

Hy everyone, I'm not being able to run my windows application in VB 2008 without internet connection. If I am connected to internet everything works fine but when I'm not connected, after clicking 'Start Debugging' I get this error:

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve it? Please help.